# jquery storing container contents along with form selections in variable

Tags: jquery, html, html-select, forms

I'm not sure this is possible so let me know if I am asking the impossible but I have a JSP page which contains a form which is bound to a model from spring MVC.
I have a button which when clicked stores the contents of a div in a javascript variable. The form is contained within this div. The div contents are then replaced with some other HTML. This is the JSP page...

```
<input id="linkEntity" type="button" value="Link" />
<input id="storeDiv" type="button" value="store" />

<div id="div1">
    <form:form id="form1" method="post" modelAttribute="model" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/save">
        <select name="ethnicity" >
            <option value="">Please select</option>
                <c:forEach items="${ethnicityList}" var="et">
                    <option value="${et.code}" <c:if test="${et.code == model.ethnicity}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${et.desc}</option>
                </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </form:form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var origDiv = "";
        $("body").on("click", "#storeDiv", function() {
            origDiv = $("#div1").html();
            $("#div1").html("replace div with other contents..");
        });
        $("body").on("click", "#linkEntity", function() {
            $("#div1").html(origDiv );
        });

    });
</script>
```

What I would like to happen is if say a selection has been made in the select element, can I record this somehow and have that value selected when I replace the div contents with the original HTML?

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var origDiv = $("#div1").html();
    $("body").on("click", "#storeDiv", function() {
        $("#div1").html("replace div with other contents..");
    });
    $("body").on("click", "#linkEntity", function() {
        $("#div1").html(origDiv );
    });
});
```

Comment: This is basically the same as I have. I need form inputs and select options to be recorded in the origDiv javascript variable if possible.Not just the options and inputs on page load but any changes to form made by user.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution...
Create another empty js variable called formselections on page load..

```
var formselections = "";
```

At point where original html is stored in js variable, populate another js variable with form values using..

```
formselections = $("#form1").serializeArray();
```

Then when you put the original html back in the container, iterate over this variable setting your form elements to the recorded value like this..

```
$.each(formselections, function(i, e) {
    $("#form1 [name="+e.name+"]").val(e.value);
});
```